# Create translation from translation, not from source

Tags: translation, gettext, poedit

There are two files, a **German template file** (`de.pot`), generated **from source**, and an **English translation** in `en.po`.

- `de.pot`
- `en.po`

Now someone non-German wants to translate the application. But from the surface, it seems *Poedit* only allows creating translations from source (which is German). What's the workflow to create an **en → fr** translation, for example, for this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Translating from translation (or worse, of a translation of a translation of a…) is a bad idea. It leads to serious accuracy and understandability issues.

If you don't have other options (using English for the source being the canonical one), you can use the [poswap](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/poswap.html) tool to do it.

Comment: So, if you suggest not doing it, is there a way to migrate my German source (Python) files? By automatically swapping German strings and English strings?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas Manually I'm afraid or using your own search-and-replace script.